# Passing php array data to a js file

Tags: javascript, php

I've got some data in the following array.

```
$seats = array();
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    $seats[] = $book;
}
```

Here the result is:

```
  Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 50 ).
```

How can I pass this data to another JS file as follows?

```
//Case II: If already booked
var bookedSeats = [10, 50];
init(bookedSeats);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
//Case II: If already booked
var bookedSeats = <?= json_encode($seats) ?>;
init(bookedSeats);
```

Comment: You cant really, just define your `bookedSeats` var before you include the external file, then the code can access it fine.

Comment: I have no idea.could you please give a sample code?

Comment: Actually it should work fine your passing it as a construct to init.

Comment: Update your question with your current code so can see how your doing it, or open a new question.

Comment: Alright,I've done it using an internal JS file and your suggestion works fine!Thank you so much!!!